# using paste command in a loop

Tags: bash, unix, awk, paste

I am using Fedora, and bash to do some text manipulation with the files I have. I am trying to combine a large number of files, each one with two columns of data. From these files, I want to extract the data on the 2nd column of the files, and put it in a single file. Previously, I used the following script:

```
paste 0_0.dat 0_6.dat 0_12.dat | awk '{print $1, $2, $4}' >0.dat
```

But this is painfully hard as the number of files gets larger -- trying to do with 100 files. So I looked through the web to see if there's a way to achieve this in a simple way, but come up empty-handed.

I'd like to invoke a 'for' loop, if possible -- for example,

```
for i in $(seq 0 6 600)
do
  paste 0_0.dat | awk '{print $2}'>>0.dat
done
```

but this does not work, of course, with paste command.

Please let me know if you have any recommendations on how to do what I'm trying to do ...

DATA FILE #1 looks like below (deliminated by a space)

```
-180 0.00025432
-179 0.000309643
-178 0.000189226
.
.
.
-1 2E-5
0 1.4E-6
1 0.00000
.
.
.
178 0.0023454268
179 0.002352534
180 0.001504992
```

DATA FILE #2

```
-180 0.0002352
-179 0.000423452
-178 0.00019304
.
.
.
-1 2E-5
0 1.4E-6
1 0.00000
.
.
.
178 0.0023454268
179 0.002352534
180 0.001504992
```

**First column goes from -180 to 180, with increment of 1.**

DESIRED 
(n is the # of columns; and # of files)

```
-180 0.00025432 0.00025123 0.000235123 0.00023452 0.00023415 ... n
-179 0.000223432 0.0420504 0.2143450 0.002345123 0.00125235 ... n
.
.
.
-1 2E-5
0 1.4E-6
1 0.00000    
.
.
.
179 0.002352534 ... n
180 0.001504992 ... n
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show some sample data and your desired result?

Comment: Are all the files located in the same directory?

Comment: yes these files are located in the same directory.

Comment: you mean that your output will have output with first column like `-180`, and then 100's of columns with the rest of the values associated with `-180`, yes? Please indicate that in your sample output like `-180 0.00025432 0.00025123 0.000235123 0.00023452 0.00023415 ...... n`. Also, so we know how much data your're dealing with, please edit post with result of `du -sk .`. Good luck.

Comment: post edited based on shelter's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
paste "$@" | awk '{ printf("%s", $1); 
for (i = 2; i < NF; i += 2) 
       printf(" %s", $i); printf "\n"; 
}'
```

This assumes that you don't run into a limit with `paste` (check how many open files it can have).  The `"$@"` notation means 'all the arguments given, exactly as given'. The `awk` script simply prints `$1` from each line of pasted output, followed by the even-numbered columns; followed by a newline.  It doesn't validate that the odd-numbered columns all match; it would perhaps be sensible to do so, and you could code a vaguely similar loop to do so in `awk`.  It also doesn't check that the number of fields on this line is the same as the number on the previous line; that's another reasonable check.  But this does do the whole job in one pass over all the files - for an essentially arbitrary list of files.

---

> I have 100 input files -- how do I use this code to open up these files?

You put my original answer in a script 'filter-data'; you invoke the script with the 101 file names generated by `seq`.  The `paste` command pastes all 101 files together; the `awk` command selects the columns you are interested in.

```
filter-data $(seq --format="0_%g.dat" 0 6 600)
```

The `seq` command with the format will list you 101 file names; these are the 101 files that will be pasted.

You could even do without the `filter-data` script:

```
paste $(seq --format="0_%g.dat" 0 6 600) | awk '{ printf("%s", $1); 
for (i = 2; i < NF; i += 2) 
printf(" %s", $i); printf "\n"; 
}'
```

I'd probably go with the more general script as the main script, and if need be I'd create a 'one-liner' that invokes the main script with the specific set of arguments currently of interest.

The other key point which might be a stumbling block: `paste` is not limited to 2 files only; it can paste as many files as you can have open (give or take about 3).

Comment: @leffler: I don't understand this. I have 100 input files -- how do I use this code to open up these files?

Answer (score 2):

`join` can get you your desired result.

```
join <(sort -r file1) <(sort -r file2)
```

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file1
-180 0.00025432
-179 0.000309643
-178 0.000189226
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file2
-180 0.0005524243
-179 0.0002424433
-178 0.0001833333
[jaypal:~/Temp] join <(sort -r file1) <(sort -r file2)
-180 0.00025432 0.0005524243
-179 0.000309643 0.0002424433
-178 0.000189226 0.0001833333
```

To do multiple files at once, you can use it with `find` command -

```
find . -type f -name "file*" -exec join '{}' +
```

Comment: yes... but I still have to type in file1, file2, file3 ... file100. Trying to stay away from writing all the file names.

Comment: @Greg Thats true, what you can do is do this in conjunction with `find` command which will find all your files and do `join`.

Comment: If I do this, the data are not sorted -- for example, the column 2 of file 1 will precede the column 2 of file 10, so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my assumptions that you see in the comments above, you don't need paste. Try this

```
awk '{
  arr[$1] = arr[$1] "\t" $2 }; 
  END {for (x=-180;x<=180;x++) print  x "\t" arr[x]
 }' *.txt \
| sort -n
```

Note that we just take all of the values into an array based on the value in the first field, and append values based on the $1 key. After all data has been read in, The END section prints out the key and the value. I've added things like `"x="`, `":vals= "` to help 'explain' what is happening. Remove those for completely clean tab-seperated data. Change '\t' to ':' or '|', or ... shudder ',' if  you need to. Change the `*.txt` to what every your filespec is.

Be aware that all Unix command lines have limitations to the number and size (length of filenames, not the data inside), of filenames that can be processed in 1 invocation.  Let us know if you get error messages about that.

The pipe to sort ensures that data is sorted by column1.

With my test data, the output was

```
-178            0.0001892261    0.0001892262    0.0001892263    0.000189226
-179            0.0003096431    0.0003096432    0.0003096433    0.000309643
-180            0.000254321     0.000254322     0.000254323     0.00025432
178             0.0001892261    0.0001892262    0.0001892263    0.000189226
179             0.0003096431    0.0003096432    0.0003096433    0.000309643
180             0.000254321     0.000254322     0.000254323     0.00025432
```

Based on 4 files of input.

Comment: @Shelter: I've added a few more details about the text file.

Comment: See revised. I duplicated the neg. values in my test file and deleted the '-' sign for 1/2 the records.

Comment: @shelter: thanks, but the column 1 should go from -180 to 180 with an increment of 1.

Comment: What is in your file, random values between -180 and 180 and an incomplete set? I can fix that if need be. What do you expect for blank lines of data, 0 values?

Comment: sort -n to sort in number order instead of text order.

Comment: So there's a special case in the middle of the data range? Will those values change, can I use static code to insert them?

Comment: there's no special case. the number for the first column goes from -180 to 180 with an increment of 1. i.e., -180, -179, -178, -177, -176, -175, -174 ... -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180

Comment: are there N columns for -1, 0, and 1, your sample doesn't show that.

Comment: ok wait one sec, I understand the cuase of miscommuncation (on my part).

Comment: Try it now. Also thanks to @theglauber (I did have -n in my dev environment, but didn't copy it over!) Also fixes to END loop now in place. it should work.

Comment: N is the number of files, and since I am trying to extract 2nd column from these data, is equal to number of columns

Comment: I don't want to be bother modifying your test data again. The script above does print all values between -180 and 180, even if they're not in the data. Don't be distracted by the fact that my sample output doesn't have -1, 0, 1 records, it should work. Did you try it? Good luck.

Comment: thanks shellter but there's another problem -- the 2nd column for file name 1.txt appears after 10.txt. I want it to be sorted by the name of the file so that the column from 1.txt will precede 2.txt, 10.txt, 100.txt, so forth. I think it's almost there though.

Comment: Then the easiest solution is to recreate your files with names that will naturally sort when the command line expansion of '*' happens,  like 001.txt 010.txt 100.txt. You can post a separate question here on S.O. to learn out to do that. You'll get extra rep point for it too. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo *.dat | sed 's/\S*/<(cut -f2 &)/2g;s/^/paste /' | bash >all.dat
```